# Is there a way to verify that Kerberos is used?

Tags: kerberos, adam

I am using System.DirectoryServices namespace for communicating with an ADAM instance. Part of the network within our organization Kerberos, while another defaults to NTLM. We also have conflicting domains (aliased the same ABC), that have different fully resolved names, of course.
Kerberos requires usage of fully resolved names, as far as I understand. My ADAM instances (multiple, replicated) are pointed to by WideIP, which resolves to different IPs for different regions. One of those WideIPs is serving "me" an alias instead of FQDN, which makes my ADAM go to the wrong domain.
The questions are:
- is there a way to verify that kerberos is used in communication with that ADAM?
and
- is there a way to force kerberos (which could be used to error out early)
Thank you for looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine showed me a couple of good tools that did the job:

- [**WireShark**](http://www.wireshark.org/) makes tracing communications protocols a snap. Great tool. It traces net packets. You will see exactly where Kerberos digresses to NTLM.
- [**KerbTray**](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23018) is somewhat useful too.

Hope it will help someone.